# Compling error Class 'does not name a type' dispite header file being included

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, header-files

I am a beginner in the C++ language and have run into a compiling error that has stumped me for days for my latest assignment. 
The code is using a class GradeBook to set both the name of the course and the instructor's name.

Here is the driver file where I include the header file that contains the class GradeBook

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GradeBook.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    gradeBook gradeBook1 ();
    gradeBook gradeBook2 ();

    cout << "Grade Book Initial Course Name: \n" << gradeBook1.getCourseName() << endl;
    cout << "Initial Instructor Name: \n" << gradeBook2.getInstuctorName() << endl;

    gradeBook.displayMessage();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the header file. I added in the #ifndef to prevent possible looping errors based on research into this problem.

```
#ifndef GRADE_H
#define GRADE_H


#include <string>
#include "GradeBook.cpp"

// __Grade_Book__
class GradeBook
{
    std::string courseName, instructorName;

public:
    // constructor initializes courseName with string  supplied an argument
    GradeBook( std::string name);

    //function sets the course name and limits length
   void setCourseName(std::string name);
   void setInstructorName(std::string iName);


    //function gets the course name
    std::string getCourseName();
    std::string getInstructorName();

    //function displays a welcome message
    void displayMessage();

};
#endif
```

This is the source file where the error " 'GradeBook' does not name a type' occurs at the first instance of GradeBook despite being linked to the header file. I feel as though this file is not completely necessary for this code but it is required for the assignment. I'm wondering if I have messed up with the communication of the files creating a loop but everything I have tried has led to the same compiling error, insisting that the class GraddeBook has not been defined.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GradeBook.h"

using namespace std;



// constructor initializes courseName with string supplied an argument

GradeBook::GradeBook(string name)

{
    setCourseName(name);
    setInstructorName (iName);
     // call set function to initialize courseName
}
//function sets the course name
void GradeBook::setCourseName(string name)
{
    if (name.length() <= 30)
        courseName = name;
    else
    {
        courseName = name.substr(0, 30); //start at 0, length of 30
        cout << "Course Name \" " << name << "\" exceeds maximum length (30).\n"
        << "Limiting courseName to the first 30-characters.\n" << endl;
    }
}
void GradeBook::setInstuctorName(string iName)
{
    if (iName.length() <= 20)
        instructorName = iName;
    else
    {
        instructorName = iName.substr(0, 30); //start at 0, length of 30
        cout << "Instructor Name \" " << iName << "\" exceeds maximum length (20).\n"
        << "Limiting Instructor Name to the first 20-characters.\n" << endl;
    }
}

//function gets the course name
string GradeBook::getCourseName()
{
    return courseName;
}

string GradeBook::getInstructorName()
{
    return InstructorName;
}
//function displays a welcome message
void GradeBook::displayMessage()
    {
        cout << "Welcome to the Grade book for: \n" << getCourseName() << endl;
        cout << "This course is presented by: \n" << getInstructorName() << endl;
    }
```

Comment: remove `#include "GradeBook.cpp"` from GradeBook.h

Comment: thanks, I wasnt sure if that was needed. realized another part of my problem was that the files werent in a single project folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to use the correct classname when declaring a variable. Identifiers are case sensitive.

```cpp
    GradeBook gradeBook1;
    GradeBook gradeBook2;
```

Comment: thanks for the catch, I'm now past this class error.